# Combined HDDs into one after formating Windows

Tags: windows, hard-drive

I'm using Windows 10 Pro N and I have combined (using Disk Management from Windows 10) two physical HDDs (1TB + 320GB) into an one just to have one combined space. Those two disk are only for data, there's no OS on them. Windows 10 runs on different disk (SSD).

My question is: If I formated my SSD and re-install Windows 10, would I be able to see my data? Would they be affected?

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend creating a ***BACK UP*** of any important data before a process like this. It is to easy to make a simply mistake and lose everything.

There are a a few issues to talk about here:

First, your data will survive the installation.  However, you will not be able to access it immediately.  You will have to go into `Disk Management` to import the spanned volume.  When in `Disk Management` you will see the disks listed as `Foreign`.  Right click one and import it.  It will bring a dialog box showing other disks in the spanned volume.  Make sure the other disk is selected and click "OK".  The spanned volume will now show up as a drive.  However, you are not done yet. Since you erased your previous installation, your current *user* does not have access to the data.  You will need to take ownership of the drive and give your new user permission to the data.  I wont go into detail on that, as there are countless guides you can Google for.  It is an easy process.  Once all these steps are complete, you are finished with the entire process.

I do want to point out that spanning disks should be avoided if possible.  It offers no redundancy or speed improvements that even software RAID does.  Spanning disks writes to the first disk in the group until it is full, then moves to the next.  If your 1 TB disk is the first in the group and is not full, you havent even touched the 320 GB disk.  Disk spanning adds a layer of complexity and more points of failure.  If the 1 TB is currently sufficient for your data, then I would drop the 320 GB drive.

Alternatively, Windows 10 has a `Reset this PC` [option](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/reset-your-windows-10-system-with-the-keep-my-files-option/).  I have never used this feature, so I dont actually know what will happen.  If you select the `keep my files option`, it should retain your original user.  What I dont know is if will keep your disk span.  If it does keep your disk span, than, in theory,this could do everything you need.  It couldnt hurt to try it, worst case you just have to go through the process listed above.